# Matrix Elements Ratio Control

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, probability

I am using the code

```py
import numpy as np
P=np.random.choice([0, 1], (10000, 10, 10, 10))
```

to generate 10,000 3D binary matrices. But I need to control the ratio of ones to zeros in each of the matrices. What I mean is that for any given matrix, I want 70% of its elements to be 1 and the rest to be 0. Is there a way for doing so? A probabilistic approach would work as well. For example, if, for any given matrix, the probability of each of its elements to be 1 could be equal to 70% that would work too.

Comment: I think this is what you may need: `np.random.binomial(1,0.7,  (10000, 10, 10, 10))`
Source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html?highlight=binomial#numpy.random.binomial

Comment: Thanks. Does this control the ratio in the overall 4d array?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late answer, so you could control the ratio of each subarray item by giving array-like parameters for `n` and `p`. However, these would have to have the same shape as the output parameter, where in each element you can set the probability for the corresponding element in the output array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify probablity parameter in [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```py
import numpy as np

size = (10000, 10, 10, 10)
prob_0 = 0.3 # 30% of zeros
prob_1 = 1 - prob_0 # 70% of ones

P = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=size, p=[prob_0, prob_1])
```

However this will allow to control the ratio in the overall 4d array, not in each sub-array.

Comment: Does this code (`np.random.binomial(1,0.7,  (10000, 10, 10, 10))`) control the ratio in the overall 4D array as well?

Comment: No it doesn't either.

Comment: I appreciate your kind help. It's so helpful.